# Dragging images from a scrollable region in Raphael?

Tags: drag-and-drop, svg, raphael

I'm investigating the feasibility of using Raphael for a user-research project. One of the features allows for users to drag images onto a canvas and we record where they placed it. The pool of images is potentially quite large and we'll have them in a scrollable box in the tool.

I put together a quick wireframe of the issue I'm looking into since it'll probably be clearer than my explanation.

Please see the wireframe:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd stick with straight HTML/CSS and use jQueryUI draggables, as you mention in your comment.

You don't *appear* to need any of the drawing/display features SVG offers, yet if you went that route, you'd have to build your own custom scrolling behavior (instead of setting a CSS overflow-y rule) and picture layout algorithms (again instead of using CSS floats or something).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a scrollable region using Raphael.

1. Create the viewport with fixed
   dimensions (say 800x600)
2. Draw the images with increasing y value. After few images, the y value will go beyond 600. It will be drawn but will not be visible in the viewport.
3. Create a scrollbar using raphael rects. Attach drag events to the scrollbar handle rect.
4. When the handle is moved, translate all the images accordingly.

   For e.g. lets assume in step 2, you had drawn all the images and the bottom most point of the end image is having y value 2000. Assuming the scrollbar has length 500, each dx movement of the handle will have to translate 2000/500 = 4dx. You can calculate the handle length similarly using ratios.

Since everything inside a single Raphael paper the dragging of images will work seamlessly. You will have to maintain the positions of each images.

Comment: Thanks TigrisC. I hadn't thought of implementing my own scrollbars, but I follow what you're describing. I guess I need to decide if this direction is worth the effort in comparison to a more vanilla jQueryUI drag/drop implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this demo similar
Remember you can always use getBBox when you drop. In this case it's rects but images would be the same..

http://irunmywebsite.com/raphael/additionalhelp.php?q=bearbones

Comment: I got your reply.
Each one of the boxes and images "know" where they are and what their dimensions are 2.
I don't mind helping so give us a shout, you have the email. Also would you be allowed/able to use php on the server side?
Eg Maybe you need to upload these images?